# LeetCode 146: LRU Cache II

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, python-3.x, programming-challenge

I'm posting my code for a LeetCode problem. If you'd like to review, please do so.

#### Problem

> - Design and implement a data structure for Least Recently Used (LRU) cache. It should support the following operations: get and put.
> - get(key) - Get the value (will always be positive) of the key if the key exists in the cache, otherwise return -1.
> - put(key, value) - Set or insert the value if the key is not already present. When the cache reached its capacity, it should invalidate the
>   least recently used item before inserting a new item.
> - The cache is initialized with a positive capacity.
>
> Follow up:
>
> - Could you do both operations in O(1) time complexity?
>
> #### Example:
>
> ```cpp
> LRUCache cache = new LRUCache( 2 /* capacity */ );
>
> cache.put(1, 1);  
> cache.put(2, 2);  
> cache.get(1);       // returns 1  
> cache.put(3, 3);    // evicts key 2  
> cache.get(2);       // returns -1 (not found)  
> cache.put(4, 4);    // evicts key 1  
> cache.get(1);       // returns -1 (not found)  
> cache.get(3);       // returns 3  
> cache.get(4);       // returns 4
> ```

#### Accepted Python

```
class LRUCache:
    def __init__(self, capacity: int) -> None:
        self.cache = {}
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.next = {}
        self.prev = {}
        self.head = 'HEAD'
        self.tail = 'TAIL'
        self.connect(self.head, self.tail)

    def connect(self, node_a: int, node_b: int) -> None:
        self.next[node_a], self.prev[node_b] = node_b, node_a

    def remove(self, key: int) -> None:
        self.connect(self.prev[key], self.next[key])
        del(self.prev[key], self.next[key], self.cache[key])

    def append(self, key: int, val: int) -> None:
        self.cache[key] = val
        self.connect(self.prev[self.tail], key)
        self.connect(key, self.tail)
        if len(self.cache) > self.capacity:
            self.remove(self.next[self.head])

    def get(self, key: int) -> int:
        if key not in self.cache:
            return -1
        val = self.cache[key]
        self.remove(key)
        self.append(key, val)
        return val

    def put(self, key: int, val: int) -> None:
        if key in self.cache:
            self.remove(key)
        self.append(key, val)
```

#### LeetCode's Solution (Not for review)

```
class DLinkedNode(): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.key = 0
        self.value = 0
        self.prev = None
        self.next = None
            
class LRUCache():
    def _add_node(self, node):
        """
        Always add the new node right after head.
        """
        node.prev = self.head
        node.next = self.head.next

        self.head.next.prev = node
        self.head.next = node

    def _remove_node(self, node):
        """
        Remove an existing node from the linked list.
        """
        prev = node.prev
        new = node.next

        prev.next = new
        new.prev = prev

    def _move_to_head(self, node):
        """
        Move certain node in between to the head.
        """
        self._remove_node(node)
        self._add_node(node)

    def _pop_tail(self):
        """
        Pop the current tail.
        """
        res = self.tail.prev
        self._remove_node(res)
        return res

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        """
        :type capacity: int
        """
        self.cache = {}
        self.size = 0
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.head, self.tail = DLinkedNode(), DLinkedNode()

        self.head.next = self.tail
        self.tail.prev = self.head
        

    def get(self, key):
        """
        :type key: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        node = self.cache.get(key, None)
        if not node:
            return -1

        # move the accessed node to the head;
        self._move_to_head(node)

        return node.value

    def put(self, key, value):
        """
        :type key: int
        :type value: int
        :rtype: void
        """
        node = self.cache.get(key)

        if not node: 
            newNode = DLinkedNode()
            newNode.key = key
            newNode.value = value

            self.cache[key] = newNode
            self._add_node(newNode)

            self.size += 1

            if self.size > self.capacity:
                # pop the tail
                tail = self._pop_tail()
                del self.cache[tail.key]
                self.size -= 1
        else:
            # update the value.
            node.value = value
            self._move_to_head(node)
```

#### Reference

On LeetCode, there is a class usually named `Solution` with one or more `public` functions which we are not allowed to rename.

- [146. LRU Cache - Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/lru-cache/)
- [146. LRU Cache - Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/lru-cache/discuss/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something smells funny here:

```
    self.head = 'HEAD'
    self.tail = 'TAIL'
    self.connect(self.head, self.tail)

def connect(self, node_a: int, node_b: int) -> None:
```

Those are strings, not integers. Briefly looking through your code, there's nothing requiring that your node keys be integers; they only need to be *hashable*. This is probably what you want to use for your type hints:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Hashable

Beyond that, though, I question using those strings for HEAD and TAIL. It would be safer to make sentinel objects `self.head = object(); self.tail = object()` that will not match anything the user provides.